# Why this code result is undefined?

Tags: javascript

```
function aaa() {
  return
  {
    test: 1
  }
}

console.log(aaa());
```

Why this code result is undefined?
I assume is will be object.

Answer (score 0):

Because when you change the line it terminate the statement so you have to put curly bracket after `return` to make it work.

Just use this:

```
function aaa() {
  return {
    test: 1
  }
}

console.log(aaa());
```

Comment: “Just use this” is not an answer to “Why this code result is undefined?”.

Comment: Curious to know the difference between your code and OP's code.

Comment: becouse when you change the line it terminate the statment so you have to put curly braces after return to make it work if i helped then accept the answer

Comment: i guess i have already tell the answer in my last comment

Comment: @user2779185 It’d be better to [edit] your answer and include that comment, since that’s the explanation that is actually answering the question and that’s what’s missing in order to make your answer relevant. Though, this question unfortunately is a duplicate and as such already has an answer…